# Why isn't xcode displaying MainStoryBoard?

Tags: xcode

I'm confused. I'm following a course for app development and we are reading "Teach Yourself iPhone OS Application Development" when I open the files at the school's computer it shows the mainstoryboard but it's not displaying it in my laptop? I made sure I'm using the same version of Xcode and the same files.

[image]

Comment: I aslo get these errors http://gyazo.com/03a2685fde27b67056162313101466f9.png?1353539686

Comment: are you opening the exact same project? (By this i mean did you copy the whole folder)

Comment: yes sir. http://gyazo.com/99f1ec7930360b29bd84fda8e9fecfaf.png?1353547082 this are all the folders and files. The same project I open in over my school.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are looking at XIB files and not storyboard files.

XIB files usually contain single view controllers (and other objects), while storyboards (usually one storyboard per architecture) have multiple view controllers and segues to nicely get between them.

If you want to see changes to the UI within the program created by project you've created a screenshot of, you'll need to modify the files with the "`.xib`" extension.  Both storyboards and XIB files are editable with Xcode's built in Interface Builder functionality.

Comment: You are right. I just found this screenshot of how it looks in my school's computer http://gyazo.com/0a70514d5a3ccac616f7ff1c898e05da.png?1353540166 is it possible to make it display that way?

Comment: Easiest way to do this, for a newbie to Xcode, would be just to create a brand new Xcode project and make sure (when creating the project) that the "use storyboards" checkbox is set to **ON** (it's on the same modal panel where you enter in the name of your new app).

Comment: I did get the storyboard by creating a new project checking "use storyboard" but I still can't figure it out how to change the existing project to display the storyboard. I'm really sorry, I'm really new to this tool. So you are saying I can do this by modifying the files with .xib extension? What files exactly? This are all the folders and files of the project http://gyazo.com/99f1ec7930360b29bd84fda8e9fecfaf.png?1353547082  Thanks a bunch for the help.